# Are Unupvote/undownvote votes captured in SEDE?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, data-explorer

I'm trying to calculate some year-end statistics and extracted some data from [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com). However, it is not clear how to identify regular up-vote/down-vote retractions (typically called Unupvote/Undownvote). The [vote types](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types) only list `UpMod` (2) and `DownMod` (3).

Are unupvote/undownvote votes captured in SEDE... anywhere? If not, can this be added as a vote type?

#### Motivation:

Ideally I'd like to recreate the community's activity on a day-to-day basis (the finest time-frame available since votes don't include a time-stamp). To that end one may be able to track how voting (or reputation) is bestowed (positive or negative) throughout the year, perhaps grouped by post. It would allow one to recreate the community state (so to speak) at any given day for analysis purposes and may highlight interesting communal tendencies.

As of now it is not possible without some form of reference to vote removal/reversal. One would only be able to approximate the community state for a given day, with varied accuracy.

Comment: I'd be surprised if they were even stored _anywhere_ internally, let alone in the part of the dump that goes to SEDE. For what it's worth, I've been in SEDE quite a bit lately and am not aware of un-votes being captured anywhere.

Comment: I suspect it's probably recorded as a deletion timestamp on the original vote (if the vote record is preserved at all), but Data Explorer never exposes any "deleted" data. It's definitely not in there now, but I can't comment on whether or not there's any chance of it being added.

Comment: @senshin it looks like they are stored _somewhere_ internally; as an example, my rep history at Programmers shows me an answer undownvote I made on Dec 3, that is about 3 weeks ago

Comment: @gnat: Yes, unvoting is allowed after an edit, and therefore can occur within the given time-limit (in which case it's not recorded at all) or after the time-limit given an edit to the post. Of course, this can occur on a completely different day and therefore is listed in a different per-day reputation group (since it could affect reputation-related badges like [Mortarboard](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/50/mortarboard), [Epic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/51/epic) and [Legendary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/52/legendary)).

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not. Unupvote and undownvote events only exist as informational entries in the reputation history. In the system itself, the *original* upvote or downvote gets changed to a "deleted" state so that the system knows it no longer applies to the post. These deleted votes are not available in Data Explorer, since the DeletionDate is not made available to the public and thus including them would make results inaccurate (since you wouldn't know if the vote is actually active or not).

As far as adding all those votes and making that DeletionDate visible, you'd have to convince Stack Exchange that the data would be useful for some reason. I can't comment as to why the information isn't available already.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "you wouldn't know if the vote is actually active or not". A non-null DeletionDate (or even DeletionDate > CreationDate) should suffice in deciding its activeness.

Comment: @Werner Because the DeletionDate is not exposed currently. So if deleted votes were present in the system in the current state, you wouldn't be able to tell which ones were retracted.

Comment: How would *I* go about convincing StackExchange that such information is useful?

Comment: @Werner Construct an argument for why you need it. An example of what you'd do with the information is usually a good starting place.

Comment: I'll add this to my question, since it's referenced as a [tag:feature-request].