# Statistics about where user got reputation exactly from

Tags: feature-request, reputation

**Idea**

As the reputation plays a major part in Stack Exchange, at least I would be interested to see where did particular user got the reputation from: accepted answers, good questions, upvoted answers or from something else. There is also currently quite extensive information about the user available and I suppose you can see all reputation changes already in the list. Even though all the data is available, it would be great to get it in more handy way as aggregated.

**Why**

Why this would be interesting is the fact that users differ really much from one to other on how they behave here. For example I tend to answer questions tens of times more than to ask them. On the other hand, I rarely get upvotes for my answers even though they usually are accepted since I generally answer on questions that aren't about the major topics because there it is more of a race and I like to take my time and craft quality answers.

Enough of me and to why I even thought of this in the first place. I often just follow one quite minor tag on Stack Overflow and answer to major part of questions there. There often exist users having trouble with even the basics of programming. Still, these users have multiple times more reputation than me and I'd be interested to see where has that all reputation come from.

Also as Stack Exchange can be seen (at least on Stack Overflow side) as a good reference for future employers, it would be good to be able to easily point out what you actually are doing here. These differences on where the reputation have came from might be essential to prioritize the applicants.

**Implementation**

I haven't thought that much about the implementation part but there should be a plenty of places to put that on profile view. Here's few possible placements:

- Under *reputation* tab as a new box next to `post`, `time` and `graph`. Could be called *statistics* or *overall*.
- On the *summary* tab, under the part *reputation*.

Any ideas, comments, improvements, problems or notices to mention?

Answer (score 5):

Actually [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/220825/my-reputation-graph#graph) query is very wonderful to get this data (I first noticed it [there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277737/2963652)).

But do we care (me not)?

Comment: Can't really see how is that related when talking about feature request? Sure I can script it myself and put in on my own website, still not the same thing as having it on everyone's profile page.

Comment: @san ok my last sentence is answer sorry :)

Comment: Sure, that can be your opinion and I respect that. But based on how many upvotes that question you also shared link to got, I would assume that at least someone would care to see it as a feature.

Comment: @san and I think that those up votes for the second sentence... :D how can we know?

Comment: Please quote which sentence you are referring to?

Comment: @san "But personally I am not really concerned about knowing my rep for one type of activity".

Comment: I was talking about the question, not the answer. The original question also got 77 upvotes so I suppose some people would be interested to see the statistics for others?

Comment: Thanks for that query.  I've never cared about getting this for somebody else, but I'm sometimes curious about how my *own* reputation breaks down.  (Would love to have an aggregate view -- I've gotten X total rep from questions, Y from answers, etc, but this helps.)

Comment: Note that a selection of [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com) that uses votes does not include retracted (unupvote/undownvote) or reversed (upvote > downvote/downvote > upvote) votes. [I've made a feature request for this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246294/168244).

Answer (score -2):

This is how the reputation system works on the stack exchanges.

[Six simple tips to get reputation fast on any Stack Exchange site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast?rq=1)

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.