# What is the point of TargetRepChange when it's all zero?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, data-explorer

*All* values of the field `TargetRepChange` in the table `SuggestedEditVotes` are zero (`0`). See the [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/262104)

```
Select Sum(TargetRepChange) As [Total TargetRepChange]
From SuggestedEditVotes;
```

(or even remove the `Sum`).

Why are these values all zero (`0`)? There's no value in supplying it in this case. What would be far more beneficial is a `TargetRepChange` column in the `Votes` table - [it exists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62601/168244).

I know that [reputation calculation is complicated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126922/168244), but it would be of great value to be able to recreate the state of the site (with regards to reputation) for any point in time.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Are Unupvote/undownvote votes captured in SEDE?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246294/168244)